# Windows 7 asus p5b audio driver

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, installation

I just upgraded to an Asus P5B running Windows 7 64 bit.  For some reason, I can't play any sound.

I tried installing the [Asus Audio Driver](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5B_Deluxe/#download) but it didn't seem to work.

I also get "no audio device installed" when I hover over the loudspeaker.

### [image: No device]

I looked into the device manager and tried updating the driver. The output is as below...
[image: output form device manager]

Which driver (and where can I get it) do I need to get my sound working?

---

**update**

I got my sound working by doing a simple bios upgrade!

Comment: There are several variations of the P5B; what’s the exact model of your board?

Comment: That's also part of the problem. Can't find that out. You have a suggestion? On the box it says just P5B

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the specific model of your motherboard because there are several variations of the P5B and they use different components, so you could be installing the wrong drive altogether.

Can you look at the motherboard? Grab a flashlight and look for the id just [“above” the RAM slots](http://images.google.com/search?q=p5b&sout=1&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:l). If not, then try a system-info program like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) or [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).

---

Open the device manager (`devmgmt.msc`) and examine what the problem is. Find the audio device in the list (it may be listed as *unknown device*) and examine the error code.

---

1. Did you already try the [official drivers](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5B/#download) that Asus [provides](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?model=P5B)?
   (Their site seems to be having trouble, but they are available in the [forums](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20061223034227274&board_id=1&model=P5B%20Deluxe&) as well.)
2. Did you make sure the cables are all correct, that the speakers work, and that the volumes are all high enough?

Comment: look at my first post. I just updated it

Comment: Your edit links to the page that is not loading. Try the one in the forum (it is from 2009, so check if it is a different version from the one you have).

Comment: ok. I can't find any newer drivers. I also added a screenshot in my startpost.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications for the motherboard, you are looking for "AD1988B windows 7 64bit" drivers. A quick google search brings up this asus page, which includes the BETA driver as on your link, but also an earlier driver release. Try the earlier one.

http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=CG5290&p=14&s=11&os=29&hashedid=gV7zqgwMynk8nOEZ

Comment: I tried that one as well but get an error by installation: the audio driver files do not support your computer hardware. So i can only abort the install....

Comment: Because that’s the same one listed in the forum.

Comment: so what are the options?